The CustomPaint widget does not scroll in the ListView
How can I set the height for a CustomPaint if it is dynamic?
This is the code:
class Lab2Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const Lab2Page({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Lab 2')),
      body: const _Body(),
    );
  }
}

class _Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Body();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: ListView(
        children: const [
          _TextForm(),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          _AxisDropdownMenu(),
          _BinaryTree(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _BinaryTree extends StatelessWidget {
  const _BinaryTree();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tree = context.select((Lab2Model model) => model.tree);
    if (tree == null) return const SizedBox.shrink();
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 32;
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: BinaryTreePainter(
        tree: tree,
        width: width,
        axis: context.select((Lab2Model model) => model.axisTree),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enter image description here
I tried to make the height infinite and wrap the CustomPaint in an Intrinsic widget, but the behavior did not change.
